# Pack and unpack 3 signed integers into uint256 solidity

Tags: bit-manipulation, solidity, bit-shift

I am trying to encode 3 signed integers into 3 - 32 bits slots using bit shifting, which works fine but not with negative numbers. This could be a simple problem in C++ with the negative conversion but I never work on C++ or know any good resources to follow.

Could anyone please shed light of how to deal with a negative number in this situation?

Really appreciate it.

```
function encodeNumbers(int256 a, int256 b, int256 c) public pure returns(uint256 encoded) {

        encoded |= uint(a) << 64;

        encoded |= uint(b) << 32;

        encoded |= uint(c);

        return encoded;
    }
    
    function decodeNumber(uint256 encoded) public pure returns (int256 a, int256 b, int256 c) {

        a = int(encoded) >> 64;

        b = (int(encoded) << 192) >> 224;

        c = (int(encoded) << 224) >> 224;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Did you figure out how to do that?